# Should I instantiate MatlabControl from withing Matlab or Java?

Tags: java, matlab

It is not obvious from here http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~whitehouse/matlab/JavaMatlab.html, how to use `MatlabControl` class.

On one hand it is given an example:

> First, instantiate a MatlabControl object
>
> ```
>  MatlabControl mc = new MatlabControl();
> ```

On the other hand it is said

> Snag 1: MatlabControl objects must be instantiated from within your
>   Matlab session! (or by other java objects that were instantiated by
>   your matlab session). This is because Matlab runs its own JVM, and you
>   need to run MatlabControl in the same JVM that matlab is using. (this
>   is why you need to make sure that MatlabControl is in your matlab
>   classpath.) More specifically, if your program is defined in
>   "mypackage/MyClass.java", you need to type
>
> mypackage.MyClass.main({'param1','param2',...})

What is correct? Where to execute

```
MatlabControl mc = new MatlabControl();
```

?

In my java code?

Or at matlab command prompt?

Comment: There is no `new` keyword, so you cannot execute that in Matlab's command window. You could put that in your Java `main`, then call your package from the Command Window as specified: `mypackage.MyClass.main({'param1','param2',...})`

Comment: What does it mean "call my package from Command Window"? Suppose I need to issue `a=a+1`. Which package should I call?

Comment: Hmm, I think that before answering, we need to clarify the question. 1) You want to evaluate MATLAB stuff from Java, right? 2) In order to execute MATLAB statemets from Java, you need to create (in Java) a `MatlabControl` object, say `mc`, and then call its methods, like `mc.eval('a=a+1')`, correct? 3) In order to work on the same Java Virtual Machine as MATLAB, your Java objects -- the ones that create in turn `MatlabControl` objects to evaluate MATLAB statements -- must be created from within MATLAB. What you have written seems like a generic example.

Comment: If i will create some root object from Matlab, then I will gain no benefits of matlab in java, because I will stay in matlab. I need to stay in java but call matlab routines from there. Is it possible?

Comment: I didn't try it, but the Walktrough of last MatlabControl version  claims that is possible: https://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/wiki/Walkthrough in "Introduction." However, the proposed code template for executing MATLAB within Java is different than what you wrote.

Comment: Yes, already found that new code. But the old one usage still unclear.

Comment: The thing is: the page you refer in your post is 12 years old. Some of that info might not be actual anymore. FWIW, yes, it seems it used not to be possible to interpret MATLAB without MATLAB already running, and required calls from java objects created in the same JVM the MATLAB was using. It might not be the case anymore.